# Pattern match returns zero count

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to create regular expression pattern match for an input text. While I know for certain that the regular expression works: https://regex101.com/r/EU7fXK/1 I am unable to get this to create a match (count > 0) using code i.e.it doesnt return a match. Not sure what the reason could be.

My code looks like this

```
 static class Program
    {
        public static Regex Device { get; } = new Regex(@"\bdevice.*\b\W", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase & RegexOptions.Multiline);
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var src =
                "!######################################################################################################\r\n!# APPROVED : YES\r\n!# REASON: test1 hosts in DMZ test1x access to update manager server to maintain securMuramaty, C1TEST1TEST1XX, test1xxx\r\n!# DEVICE: xxx test1 Devices\r\n!# SECTION: test1\r\n!# REQUESTER: test1@test1test2.com\r\n!# Exp. Date : 8/2016\r\n\r\naccess-list <Rule No> permMuramat tcp <IPaddress> <subnet mask> <IPaddress> <subnet mask> eq <Port Number>\r\naccess-list <Rule No> permMuramat tcp <IPaddress> <subnet mask> <IPaddress> <subnet mask> eq <Port Number>\r\naccess-list <Rule No> permMuramat tcp <IPaddress> <subnet mask> <IPaddress> <subnet mask> eq <Port Number>\r\naccess-list <Rule No> permMuramat <IPaddress> <subnet mask> <IPaddress> <subnet mask> eq <Port Number>\r\n";

            var devices = src.GetDevice();

        }

        public static List<XElement> GetDevice(this string input)
        {
            var pattern = Device;

            var matchCollection = pattern.Matches(input);

            var elements = new List<XElement>();

            foreach (Match match in matchCollection)
            {
                var val = match.Value;

                var element = new XElement("Device") { Value = val };

                elements.Add(element);
            }
            return elements;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use OR to combine the RegexOptions:

```
RegexOptions.Multiline | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase
```